# vb.net equivalent to await foreach in c#

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

What is the VB.net equivalent to `await foreach` found in C#?

Based on what i have found VB.net's `For Each` cannot use the `Await` operator ([Await Operator (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator))

For example how would this C# example be converted to VB.net ([List blobs with Azure Storage client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet))?

```
private static async Task ListBlobsFlatListing(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, 
                                               int? segmentSize)
{
    try
    {
        // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
        var resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync()
            .AsPages(default, segmentSize);

        // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
        await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blob name: {0}", blobItem.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: VB.NET is [not evolving](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/03/12/vb-in-net-5.aspx) as a language anymore. The `await foreach` feature was therefore never ported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to write the equivalent code that a `For Each` turns into.  For a conventional (synchronous) `For Each` loop:

```vb
For Each item In Sequence
    'Do whatever with item
Next
```

Is equivalent to:

```vb
Dim iterator = Sequence.GetEnumerator()

Do While iterator.MoveNext()
    Dim item = iterator.Current
    'Do whatever with item
End Do
```

I would expect the transformation for an async enumerable to be essentially the same.

```vb
Dim iterator As IAsyncEnumerator(Of Object) 'Or appropriate type

Try
    iterator = AsyncSequence.GetAsyncEnumerator()
    Do While Await iterator.MoveNextAsync()
        Dim item = iterator.Current
        'Do whatever with item
    End Do
Finally
    Await iterator.DisposeAsync()
End Try
```

It's not quite as clean as if you could write `Await For Each` (and have proper `Using` support) but it's not too far off.

Comment: Thanks @Craig. Yes, this is what i ended up doing! As you say, not as elegant but works ;-)